# $\lim \frac{10+3^x}{20-3^x}$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $\lim \frac{10+3^x}{20-3^x}$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$

I tried $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{10+3^x}{20-3^x} =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}10+3^x}{\frac{d}{dx}20-3^x}= -\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3^x \log{3}}{3^x \log{3}} = -1.$

However, this is wrong.

EDIT: It's in fact correct. I do wish to see if there are other alternatives, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{10+3^x}{20+3^x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{3^x\left(\frac{10}{3^x}+1\right)}{3^x\left(\frac{20}{3^x}-1\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{10}{3^x}+1}{\frac{20}{3^x}-1}$$
$$=\frac{0+1}{0-1}=-1$$

Comment: You're missing a negative sign in the denominator of the first line. Other than that, great answer +1

Answer (score 3):

Factor $3^x$ in numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 3):

note that if by $\infty$ you mean the positive infinity then you should follow the Harish's. But if by $\infty$ we have the other negetive case then as 3 is greater that 1, so the limit would be $10/20$.

Comment: I get $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{10+3^{x}}{20-3^x} =\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{10+3^{-x}}{20-3^{-x}} = \frac{10+0}{20+0} =\frac{10}{20} = \frac{1}{2} $

Comment: that's right. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\frac{10+3^x}{20-3^x}=-1+\frac{30}{20-3^x}$$